# Can we 100% find Negative cycles in Bellman-Ford at n iteration?

Tags: algorithm, bellman-ford

If the distance between two points drops at n iteration,we know there must be a negative cycle.
My question is that if there is a negative cycle, will the distance between two points 100% drop at n iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not two arbitrary points, but yes, if the graph has a negative cycle, then Bellman-Ford will update at least one distance in *every* iteration, no matter how many iterations you do.

The distances on the negative cycle get smaller and smaller, approaching -infinity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ,but I wonder if there is a concrete proof about "if the graph has a negative cycle, then Bellman-Ford will update at least one distance in every iteration".

Comment: The proof is easy.  The correct distance of the vertices on and after the negative cycle is -infinity, but Bellman-Ford can decrease them by only a finite amount per iteration, therefore it takes an infinite number of iterations.  Also if any iteration fails to make a change, then all subsequent iterations will do the same, so getting an infinite number of updates requires at least one update in every iteration.

Comment: Your proof is very easy to understand! Thank you!